# Trying to remove tags but quickly running out of memory

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, out-of-memory

I'm trying to do something simple which is removing all tags from HTML code that are in rows of a very large csv file (3 GB).  I tried using beautiful soup with the following code

```
remove_tags=['p','li','ul','pre','h1']   
soup=BeautifulSoup(row[1])
for tag in remove_tags:
    for match in soup.findAll(tag):
           match.replaceWithChildren()
```

However, with such a large file, I quickly run out of memory and a memory error occurs (I even have a lot of RAM on my machine so this must use A LOT of memory).  So I was wondering if anyone knew of a less memory intensive method of doing this.  Perhaps regex could work by just removing everything with <> (however, I have no idea how to use regex)

Note: I want to remove HTML tags of all kinds.  The remove_tags list in the above code was just constructed because those were all of I could see in the data, so if there is a method where tag names do not need to be specified, that would work too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a (very) naive Regex approach:

```
import re
re.sub(r'<[^>]+>', '', row)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Would it be correct to assume that this approach is more memory efficient?

Comment: @user1893354 Glad it worked for you.  Yes, this approach would save significantly on memory.  BeautifulSoup is extremely memory-intensive because it attempts to build a complete tree-like structure for the DOM.